# How to control access to HTML pages in Tomcat 5.5 using tokens

Tags: html, tomcat, security, tomcat5.5

I have a Tomcat 5.5 server that hosts some HTML pages. I want to control the access to these pages. The incoming users' HTTP requests are supposed to have special authentication values.

What I need is to write a function that returns true/false based on the authentication value for each user request. Based on this true/false value, the user should be granted the access or not.

Any idea about how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pragmatic solution would be to create a [ServletFilter](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) and map it to all resources (`/*`). Reading your question, I guess your authentication method will not be based on sessions (JSESSIONID cookie), but on tokens part of the URL itself.

Comment: Actually I'm not using JSESSIONID cookie itself, but I'm using another cookie inside of the HTTP header (Let's call it MYSESSIONID). Using the value of this session I will be able to authenticate the user and decide whether to grant him access or not. If my pages were JSP instead of HTML, I would have been able to programatically do that from the JSP page itself.
But since I'm using HTML pages, I won't be able to do that.. that's why I need a server method (like a Tomcat solution).

Comment: From what I'm seeing in ServletFilter link you're providing, this also can only be applied to server side scripting.. is that right, or can I use it for HTML pages also?

Comment: I found this link: http://www.lumdev.net/node/2554 

It does exactly what I wanted to do

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your own [Authenticator](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/AuthenticatorBase.html) in Tomcat.

Edit:

1. Subclass the [`AuthencatorBase`](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/tomcat/catalina/5.5.23/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/AuthenticatorBase.java#AuthenticatorBase) class and implement the the abstract method `authenticate`
2. Place your jar in the lib folder of tomcat, **not** your webapp
3. specify in your [`web.xml`](http://www.google.de/search?q=web.xml+security-constraint&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3ade%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) which resources your want to protect.
4. Declare your authenticator in your `context.xml` => this technically a [`Valve`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/valve.html)
5. deploy your application and be happy!

Comment: I couldn't find a proper usage example. can you provide me with one please?

Comment: Take the `BasicAuthenticator` in the same directory.

Comment: Please elaborate more.. I found many links to the source code of BasicAuthenticator.java, but I didn't find any example of how to use it. I want to overrid the authenticate function and write my own authentication logic.. but how do I specify the URL path this authentication applies for? where would the derived class fit into my project?

Answer (score 0):

With Tomcat, you'll need to use a `Realm` to protect your pages.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/realm-howto.html

Comment: From what I read, Realm operates based on database tables representing users' and roles. In my case, I have a different mechanism to authenticate/authorize address.